# Android Studio & AndEngine Problems (Multiple dex files define Lrog/andengine/BuildConfig)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, andengine

SO, I've been using a book to learn AndEngine (Quite fun and exciting and I was just getting into the Physics Extension) and it was designed for Eclipse and I really prefer Android Studio, so I had to figure out how to get AndEngine and the Physics Box2d extension added in. I got that, but now I get this very perplexing error. I've googled it and searched here and found similar issues, but I'm not understanding both the issue and the answers.

My project was working GREAT until this last update to Android Studio and all went to pots. Now I've created a new project, re-imported the AndEngine libraries and am still getting this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdLo2.png

```
Multiple dex files define Lorg/andengine/BuildConfig
```

I understand then that supposedly the library is somehow being included twice. What I currently have is a folder in my project called `third_party` which I'm going to rename to `libraries`. Inside of that folder is:

```
AndEngine
AndEnginePhysics2DExtension
```

Both of those have the necessary `build.gradle` files. What I'm stumbling on is some posts say to remove duplicate .jar files but I can't figure how in Android Studio how to check off or change the multiple definitions.

Any help/advice would be so much appreciated! I'm sure its something simply that I'm simply missing.

### Update

I was able to fix that problem with this solution:

## Solution

Well, just found the answer! Both the andengine package and the andenginephysics2d package had the same package name in the Manifest file! Corrected the physics package name and viola!

Comment: Except now I get this: `6438-6455/learningandengine.rggames.com.andenginediscovery E/AndEngine﹕ GameActivity.onCreateScene failed. @(Thread: 'GLThread 16250')
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load andenginephysicsbox2dextension from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/learningandengine.rggames.com.andenginediscovery-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/learningandengine.rggames.com.andenginediscovery-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null`

Comment: Forgot file structure must match class naming